# How to update Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop?

Tags: c#, windows, esent

we create some libary with 'Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop'. After run on another PC I got this exception:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

On our PC we have both versions '10.0.0.0' and '6.3.0.0' placet at

> \Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\microsoft.isam.esent.interop\v4.0_10.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.dll

and

> \Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\microsoft.isam.esent.interop\v4.0_6.3.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.dll

But, production has only '6.3.0.0'. So, I have a couple of questions:

1. How can I update 'Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.dll' version from '6.3' to '10.0'?
2. Need I to compile with old version for working?
3. Or, how may I make support for both versions?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to include the library in your deployment? If the assembly is not found in the global cache the resolver will try to find it in the path of the executable.

Comment: No, how can I do it?

In '.csproj' I used only:
"
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop"/>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
"

Comment: Not sure how you are deploying your solution, if you are creating an installer, copying manually the files... The easiest is to copy the library to the application folder in the server.

Comment: This is DLL. I has a script that copy it on PC then call some methods from Powershell.I try add Esent library to same folder but has same result.

Comment: Copy it manually to the server folder where you have deployed your app.

Comment: So, DLL version depends on Win version, because new Win versions has new data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DLL versions depends on Win version, because new Win versions has new data types.